# open source software to make screencast?

Tags: open-source, windows-7

What is a good screencasting open source tool? OBS was a good tool, but it doesn't do much high definition videos. Is there a better alternative? It should…

- support 25 or 24fps
- record in at least 1080p (similar to YouTube's HD video).
- be open-source
- work on Windows 7

Basically, by [screencasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screencast), I mean to record what ever is going on, on my screen and output it as a video footage.

Comment: Every time I've needed to screen record Windows I've used a vm on my Linux box, and run gtkrecordmydesktop...   However, I do know that VLC - www.videolan.org - can capture desktop, stream it out, etc. Just not sure if it can support the framerate and resolution you specify.

Comment: @Izzy, Basically, by screencasting, I mean to record what ever is going on, on my screen and output it as a video footage.

Comment: Thanks, integrated that with your post (note that you always can [edit] your own posts to add details or give them some other "polish"). That complies with how Wikipedia describes the term, so I've included that link. Good hunting then!

Comment: @Izzy, do you not know any out there?

Comment: If I would, I had placed an answer :) No, my only Windows are for light and fresh air. On my computers I run Linux.

Comment: @Izzy, oh, so there are for linux then, I do have linux on a dual boot.(And good dialogue, ;-)  )

Comment: That might well be. But same as above: I cannot place an answer as I'm not using any.